# flutter app failing to run using iOS simulator

Tags: xcode, flutter, visual-studio-code, ios-simulator, flutter-run

I am running into this error when trying to run my flutter app via iOS simulator
(it took 26 min to give this error)

```
                         [   +1 ms] export 'dart:js' show allowInterop, allowInteropCaptureThis;
                         [        ] ^
                         [+3310 ms] lib/screens/login_signup_screens/login.dart:188:53: Error: The method 'showSnackBar' isn't defined for the class 'ScaffoldState'.
                         [        ]  - 'ScaffoldState' is from 'package:flutter/src/material/scaffold.dart'
('../flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/material/scaffold.dart').
                         [        ] Try correcting the name to the name of an existing method, or defining a method named 'showSnackBar'.
                         [        ]                           scaffoldKey.currentState?.showSnackBar(
                         [        ]                                                     ^^^^^^^^^^^^
                         [   +8 ms] lib/screens/login_signup_screens/sign_up_screen.dart:428:51: Error: The method 'showSnackBar' isn't defined for the class
'ScaffoldState'.
                         [        ]  - 'ScaffoldState' is from 'package:flutter/src/material/scaffold.dart'
('../flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/material/scaffold.dart').
                         [        ] Try correcting the name to the name of an existing method, or defining a method named 'showSnackBar'.
                         [        ]                         scaffoldKey.currentState?.showSnackBar(
                         [        ]                                                   ^^^^^^^^^^^^
                         [+8125 ms] Unhandled exception:
                                    FileSystemException(uri=org-dartlang-untranslatable-uri:dart%3Ajs; message=StandardFileSystem only supports file:* and data:* URIs)
                                    #0      StandardFileSystem.entityForUri (package:front_end/src/api_prototype/standard_file_system.dart:34:7)
                                    #1      asFileUri (package:vm/kernel_front_end.dart:654:37)
                                    #2      writeDepfile (package:vm/kernel_front_end.dart:794:21)
                                    <asynchronous suspension>
                                    #3      FrontendCompiler.compile (package:frontend_server/frontend_server.dart:629:9)
                                    <asynchronous suspension>
                                    #4      starter (package:frontend_server/starter.dart:99:12)
                                    <asynchronous suspension>
                                    #5      main (file:///opt/s/w/ir/x/w/sdk/pkg/frontend_server/bin/frontend_server_starter.dart:13:14)
                                    <asynchronous suspension>
                     
                         [   +7 ms] Target kernel_snapshot failed: Exception
                                    #0      KernelSnapshot.build (package:flutter_tools/src/build_system/targets/common.dart:246:7)
                                    <asynchronous suspension>
                                    #1      _BuildInstance._invokeInternal (package:flutter_tools/src/build_system/build_system.dart:847:9)
                                    <asynchronous suspension>
                                    #2      Future.wait.<anonymous closure> (dart:async/future.dart:522:21)
                                    <asynchronous suspension>
                                    #3      _BuildInstance.invokeTarget (package:flutter_tools/src/build_system/build_system.dart:785:32)
                                    <asynchronous suspension>
                                    #4      FlutterBuildSystem.build (package:flutter_tools/src/build_system/build_system.dart:614:16)
                                    <asynchronous suspension>
                                    #5      AssembleCommand.runCommand (package:flutter_tools/src/commands/assemble.dart:337:32)
                                    <asynchronous suspension>
                                    #6      FlutterCommand.run.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter_tools/src/runner/flutter_command.dart:1244:27)
                                    <asynchronous suspension>
                                    #7      AppContext.run.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter_tools/src/base/context.dart:150:19)
                                    <asynchronous suspension>
                                    #8      CommandRunner.runCommand (package:args/command_runner.dart:209:13)
                                    <asynchronous suspension>
                                    #9      FlutterCommandRunner.runCommand.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter_tools/src/runner/flutter_command_runner.dart:284:9)
                                    <asynchronous suspension>
                                    #10     AppContext.run.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter_tools/src/base/context.dart:150:19)
                                    <asynchronous suspension>
                                    #11     FlutterCommandRunner.runCommand (package:flutter_tools/src/runner/flutter_command_runner.dart:229:5)
                                    <asynchronous suspension>
                                    #12     run.<anonymous closure>.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter_tools/runner.dart:63:9)
                                    <asynchronous suspension>
                                    #13     AppContext.run.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter_tools/src/base/context.dart:150:19)
                                    <asynchronous suspension>
                                    #14     main (package:flutter_tools/executable.dart:91:3)
                                    <asynchronous suspension>
                     
                         [   +3 ms] 
                                    #0      throwToolExit (package:flutter_tools/src/base/common.dart:10:3)
                                    #1      AssembleCommand.runCommand (package:flutter_tools/src/commands/assemble.dart:354:7)
                                    <asynchronous suspension>
                                    #2      FlutterCommand.run.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter_tools/src/runner/flutter_command.dart:1244:27)
                                    <asynchronous suspension>
                                    #3      AppContext.run.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter_tools/src/base/context.dart:150:19)
                                    <asynchronous suspension>
                                    #4      CommandRunner.runCommand (package:args/command_runner.dart:209:13)
                                    <asynchronous suspension>
                                    #5      FlutterCommandRunner.runCommand.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter_tools/src/runner/flutter_command_runner.dart:284:9)
                                    <asynchronous suspension>
                                    #6      AppContext.run.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter_tools/src/base/context.dart:150:19)
                                    <asynchronous suspension>
                                    #7      FlutterCommandRunner.runCommand (package:flutter_tools/src/runner/flutter_command_runner.dart:229:5)
                                    <asynchronous suspension>
                                    #8      run.<anonymous closure>.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter_tools/runner.dart:63:9)
                                    <asynchronous suspension>
                                    #9      AppContext.run.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter_tools/src/base/context.dart:150:19)
                                    <asynchronous suspension>
                                    #10     main (package:flutter_tools/executable.dart:91:3)
                                    <asynchronous suspension>
                         Failed to package /Users/ga/Downloads/ca
                         Command PhaseScriptExecution failed with a nonzero exit code
                     
                     
                         Result bundle written to path:
                                /var/folders/sq/dtjqcb_d6dl_fd5h0mrz2v3w0000gn/T/flutter_tools.rtpiTJ/flutter_ios_build_temp_dirHPXT17/temporary_xcresult_bundle
                     
                     
[+37864 ms] Could not build the application for the simulator.
[   +2 ms] Error launching application on iPod touch (7th generation).
[   +5 ms] "flutter run" took 1,635,267ms.
[  +15 ms] 
           #0      throwToolExit (package:flutter_tools/src/base/common.dart:10:3)
           #1      RunCommand.runCommand (package:flutter_tools/src/commands/run.dart:714:9)
           <asynchronous suspension>
           #2      FlutterCommand.run.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter_tools/src/runner/flutter_command.dart:1244:27)
           <asynchronous suspension>
           #3      AppContext.run.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter_tools/src/base/context.dart:150:19)
           <asynchronous suspension>
           #4      CommandRunner.runCommand (package:args/command_runner.dart:209:13)
           <asynchronous suspension>
           #5      FlutterCommandRunner.runCommand.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter_tools/src/runner/flutter_command_runner.dart:284:9)
           <asynchronous suspension>
           #6      AppContext.run.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter_tools/src/base/context.dart:150:19)
           <asynchronous suspension>
           #7      FlutterCommandRunner.runCommand (package:flutter_tools/src/runner/flutter_command_runner.dart:229:5)
           <asynchronous suspension>
           #8      run.<anonymous closure>.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter_tools/runner.dart:63:9)
           <asynchronous suspension>
           #9      AppContext.run.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter_tools/src/base/context.dart:150:19)
           <asynchronous suspension>
           #10     main (package:flutter_tools/executable.dart:91:3)
           <asynchronous suspension>
           
           
[ +151 ms] ensureAnalyticsSent: 150ms
[        ] Running 1 shutdown hook
[   +4 ms] Shutdown hooks complete
[        ] exiting with code 1
```

steps to get to this point:

1. delete Podfile.lock
2. run pod install
3. flutter clean && flutter run --verbose

here is code for login.dart:

```
onTap: () async {
                  if (formKey.currentState!.validate()) {
                    formKey.currentState!.save();
                    bool value = await Provider.of<AuthService>(context,
                            listen: false)
                        .signIn();
                    if (value.toString() == "true") {
                      Navigator.of(context).pushNamedAndRemoveUntil(
                          homeRoute, (route) => true);
                    } else {
                      scaffoldKey.currentState?.ShowSnackBar(
                          const snackBar(content: Text('Connected')));
                    }
                  }
                },
```

and it took 26min to run and give me this error. I have been trying to figure it out for nearly 2 days but nothing works! Any thoughts?

Comment: try to find the fault on the login.dart i think you imported something that cant be compiled. Also If Possible can you share the code on the file which error occur in login.dart

Comment: @ArbiterChil hmm ok. how can I share code the easiest, it is 130 lines of code?

Comment: @ArbiterChil just updated my question with some login.dart code

Comment: **scaffoldKey.currentState?** try to change this to   **scaffoldKey.currentState!**

Comment: @ArbiterChil unfortunately same error still

Comment: Could you provide a little more context, specifically where scaffoldKey is defined?